# Hibernate Ehcache clustering/replication need understanding

Tags: java, hibernate, liferay, cluster-computing, ehcache

I'm currently losing myself in hibernate understanding. Firstly let me explain, my problem.

We decide to add hibernate shared/clustered cache for a product. We got no problem in testing environnements but since this modification is publish in production we got heavy overload on CPU (at least + 1 CPU use), RAM (+1 to 3 Go) and network (bandwidth *2). This even if I disable hibernate L2 cache and query cache.
EDIT : 60 to 65 % of CPU time is spent in thread.sleep in RMI Synchronization calls.

My technical stacks :

- Liferay portal CE 6.1.1 GE2
- Ehcache 2.3 (not terracota it seems)
- Hibernate 3.X (load from liferay dependancies)
- Using liferay build service for most part of services which automatically create hibernate stack.
- 3 nodes in cluster

Now I will describe What I understand at the moment :

- Hibernate L2 cache and query cache permit to save database query by using the result in cache to avoid useless queries
- I'm using Ehcache RMI replication to shared caches
- I'm noob in hibernate ;)

Let see my hibernate - clustering configurations hibernate-clustered.xml:

```
<!--
Hibernate will use the defaultCache unless custom configurations are defined
below for individual domain objects, collection, queries, etc.
-->

<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="600"
    overflowToDisk="false"
>
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicatePuts=false,replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false"
        propertySeparator=","
    />
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" />
</defaultCache>


    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" />
</cache>
```

I search & read for more than an entire day and I continue to have doubt (and probably misunderstanding) on my thinking process. I think it's time to ask for some help !

- Firstly, I read a lot about replication and clustering. In my mind these concept are not clearly defined.  Is these process the same ? What the different, pro and cons?
- I read [in some places](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache) that ehcache (not terracota ehcache) is not compatible with cluster, what the consequences about using it like i do in small cluster, is it scalable?
- What do you think about the issue I experiment? How to explain this overhead ?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Comment: I have done my fair share of Liferay clustering, but have no clue where your problem is: Is it CPU, RAM, or network? Something must be saturated first. Also: Did you properly set up a Liferay cluster, as is laid out in the documentation (search for "cluster" on https://dev.liferay.com/)? And why are you using an outdated release? Even the already long unmaintained 6.1.x CE had more current GA releases than this one.

Comment: hi, the 3 (CPU, RAM, network) are not saturated. I forgot to add a important detail 60% of the CPU time is use in thread.sleep method in RMI communications. We follow the liferay devs documentation to set this cluster.

Comment: We are using this release cause of legacy code in application which rewrite some part of liferay in our ext module. And these part has lot of change in liferay 6.1.1 CE GA3.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. You write about "heavy overload on CPU, RAM, network", but state here that they're all not saturated. If they are not your problem, what are you fighting? Performance tuning is about finding bottleneck #1 and fixing it. Then rinse/repeat, because bottleneck #2 will have had a promotion once you're done with fixing the former #1. You'll need to find that first bottleneck. If cluster communication is indeed your bottleneck, note that there's more efficient communication module available for Liferay EE (but that would naturally require you to upgrade)

Comment: I think the overhead  is not normal. Maybe I'm wrong in this analyse. Do you have information about normal overhead with RMI replication? Moreover the CPU overhead is just Thread.sleep(). And my question was more general about replication and clustering concept. I think it's a bit confused in my mind, I need external source or explication.

Comment: I used to work  on performance issues, and how to solve performance issues. But I think my problem is more an misunderstanding problem about hibernate clustering/replication (Is it the same ? Is clustering using replication? Is it otally different?). I may reconsider the liferay 6.1.1 CE GA3 update this is not the first time somebody advise it but I think this won't solve the bottleneck. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Caches are not replicated, only invalidated - that's *typically* enough for a clustered setup: They'll be updated on next request (on a cache-miss event). Anyway - a question like "how do I do performance tuning" is quite a broad question and not a good format for stackoverflow. Suggesting to close here and bring this into the liferay.com forums

Comment: I think you're right I will try my chance on Liferay forum